# Php-generated images intermittently showing after moving to HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https

I've switched my website to use https, rather than http, and everything is fine apart from images that are generated as a result of Php code executing (static images are ok). As an example, my `phpBB` forum is one area where this is happening, where images are sporadically not showing (some are, some aren't, with no common pattern). Even simple Php scripts that generate images are showing this strange behavior. If I go back to HTTP then everything is fine.

The `error_log` contains the following (just one example of an image failing to render), It's almost as if the file generating the image does not complete its execution.

```sh
[Mon Dec 30 12:12:01.347282 2019] [core:error]
[pid 247428:tid 23291082008320] [client 90.248.211.216:0] End of script output before headers: file.php, referer: https://www.ukbutterflies.co.uk/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=9757

[Mon Dec 30 12:12:01.347709 2019] [:error]
[pid 235457:tid 23291117729536] [client 90.248.211.216:0] SoftException in Application.cpp:630: Could not execute script "/home4/ukbutte1/public_html/phpBB/download/file.php", referer: https://www.ukbutterflies.co.uk/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=9757

[Mon Dec 30 12:12:01.348063 2019] [:error]
[pid 235457:tid 23291117729536] [client 90.248.211.216:0] Caused by SystemException in API_Linux.cpp:458: execve() for program "/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi" failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, referer: https://www.ukbutterflies.co.uk/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=9757
```

The site `.htaccess` file includes the following, in case this is relevant (this is intended to direct every access request to a secure URL):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I think the key is "Resource temporarily unavailable". Send this to your hosting service provider or server administrator.

Comment: Thanks ryantxr. The hosting provider is unable to get to the bottom of this ... will provide an update if I ever manage to resolve this!